# Why is a `.get()` needed to access the headers of a Request object?

Tags: request, fetch-api, getter

I want to get the value of a Header ( 'X-Forwarded-Host' ) from [a `Request` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) and I realized the only way for me to get it is
`const forwardedHost = context?.request?.headers.get("x-forwarded-host")`
Trying to get it with
 `const forwardedHost = context?.request?.headers["x-forwarded-host"]` didn't work.

Why is that?